# Re-sample a data frame with panel dimension

Tags: r

I have a data set consisting of 2000 individuals. For each individual, `i:2000` , the data set contains `n` repeated situations. Letting `d` denote this data set, each row of `d`is indexed by `i` and `n`. Among other variables, `d` has a variable `pid` which takes on identical value for an individual across different (situations) rows.

---

Taking into consideration the panel nature of the data, I want to re-sample `d` (as in bootstrap):

- with replacement,
- store each re-sample data as a data frame

I considered using the `sample` function but could not make it work. I am a new user of r and have no programming skills.

The data set consists of many variables, but all the variables have numeric values. The data set is as follows.

```
    pid x   y   z
     1  10  2   -5
     1  12  3   -4.5
     1  14  4   -4
     1  16  5   -3.5
     1  18  6   -3
     1  20  7   -2.5
     2  22  8   -2
     2  24  9   -1.5
     2  26  10  -1
     2  28  11  -0.5
     2  30  12  0
     2  32  13  0.5
```

The first six rows are for the first person, for which `pid=1`, and the next sex rows, `pid=2` are different observations for the second person.

Comment: Use `head(d)` to show us an example of the first six rows of your dataset. You can also use `str(d)` to examine the structure of d, so we know which columns are numbers, strings, factors etc. Finally, use `dput(d)` (or `dput(d[1:10,])`) so that we may easily try our solutions on *your* data.

Comment: I hope this is helpful. I couldn't address all your requests.

Comment: What kind of sampling do you want to archive? Select n persons out ouf your 2000 and keep all observations? Select m observations for each person? A combination of both?

Comment: I want the re-sample data to have the same length (number of individuals) as the original data. That is 2000 individuals. There are n observations per individual, and if an individual is in the re-sampled data, so shall all of his or her n observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
z <- replicate(100,
               d[d$pid %in% sample(unique(d$pid), 2000, replace=TRUE),],
               simplify = FALSE)
```

The result `z` will be a list of dataframes you can do whatever with.

EDIT: this is a little wordy, but will deal with duplicated rows. `replicate` has its obvious use of performing a set operation a given number of times (in the example below, 4). I then `sample` the unique values of `pid` (in this case 3 of those values, with replacement) and extract the rows of `d` corresponding to each sampled value. The combination of a `do.call` to `rbind` and `lapply` deal with the duplicates that are not handled well by the above code. Thus, instead of generating dataframes with potentially different lengths, this code generates a dataframe for each sampled `pid` and then uses `do.call("rbind",...)` to stick them back together within each iteration of `replicate`.

```
z <- replicate(4, do.call("rbind", lapply(sample(unique(d$pid),3,replace=TRUE),
                                     function(x) d[d$pid==x,])),
                                     simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: When I run your codes, as follows
`z <- replicate(4, # four resamples
               d[d$pid %in% sample(unique(d$pid), 3, replace=TRUE),], #for each unique value in d:1-3
               simplify = FALSE)`
I got 4 resamples, but not all of them have the same number of rows.

Comment: This does work as I intended, thanks. I little more verbal explanation would have been great.

Comment: Yea, I added some additional detail; most of the code is just to handle duplicates by creating separate dataframes and then `rbind`-ing them back together with `do.call` and `rbind`. This will work to an arbitrary number of samples, duplicates, and replications.